# MSSQL PetaPoco Large Where In Query Optimisation

Tags: sql-server, orm, petapoco

I have a PetaPoco query, which is using WhereIn. Query shown below:

```
        var prodAttrCollForVariantSql = new Sql();
        prodAttrCollForVariantSql.Select("*")
            .From<ProductVariant2ProductAttributeDto>()
            .InnerJoin<ProductAttributeDto>()
            .On<ProductVariant2ProductAttributeDto, ProductAttributeDto>(left => left.ProductAttributeKey, right => right.Key)
            .WhereIn<ProductVariant2ProductAttributeDto>(x => x.ProductVariantKey, variantKeys);
```

Problem is, the 'variantKeys' is a List and could have anything from 100 to 5000+ in it.

How can I improve the performance and potential limitations of wherein in the query above?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server have a 2100 limit of parameters.

To work around it just split the list in chunks of 2000 items.
Example:

```
var Result = new List<Whatever>();
for (int i = 0; i < variantKeys.Count(); i+= 2000) {
   Result.AddRange(db.Fetch<Whatever>("SELECT * FROM Whatever WHERE ID IN (@0)", variantKeys.Skip(i).Take(2000)));
}
```